# Can't update an entry using Channel API without including title

Tags: channel, title, channel-entries-api

I'm trying to update a channel entry using the Channel API function save_entry.

```
ee()->load->library('api');
ee()->api->instantiate('channel_entries');

// Create input array
$data = array('field_id_'.$this->helper->get_field_id('booking_user') => $member_relationship);

// Update booking entry
$booking = ee()->api_channel_entries->save_entry($data, $this->channel, $booking_id);
```

This is my code and it's giving back this error

```
[29-May-2014 14:53:51 UTC] array(2) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(13) "missing_title"
  ["url_title"]=>
  string(26) "unable_to_create_url_title"
}
```

I don't want to update the title because it doesn't need to be changed.

My question is **how can I update a channel entry without including a title?**

Comment: OK, with a bit more digging I've found out that the save_entry function is actually terrible and will wipe out all data if you don't include it in the data array. Meaning I can't update one single field if I need to without including every other field in that entry. the save_entry() function is completely useless in my opinion for updating entries.

Comment: You can answer your own question after 24 hours - can you come back and do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your comments, you've already figured out the rather large annoyance of needing to pass all pre-existing fields with the save_entry function or else having them wiped out.  I wanted to post an answer here though because there are a couple considerations I've come across when doing entry updates with my add-ons:

1) If you do not need the update to trigger the EE system from explicitly noticing it and then triggering other hooks or dependencies, you can just use the [EE Database Class](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/database.html) to do a simple database update query and update that particular field directly.  This carries with it the added benefit that a session does not need to be initiated to make the update, so you can use this method for automated tasks or when the logged-in user does not have permissions.

2) If you DO need to update with save_entry in order to trigger the cascade of EE hooks and dependencies and are using a database 'select all' query to fill in your old values, then to keep the edit_date correct you need to unset the old edit_date and let EE fill this part in automatically.  I've posted an answer with some code for doing this a few weeks back, which may be of some use: [Using Channel API save_entry to update an entry](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/21311/how-do-i-update-or-edit-an-entry-using-the-channel-entries-api-save-entry-functi/21336#21336)