# trigger postmaster in an "api" request

Tags: plugin, postmaster

Hi trying to make an API call that triggers a postmaster update parcel

looked at [this post](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/21311/how-do-i-update-or-edit-an-entry-using-the-channel-entries-api-save-entry-functi)

I'm called my plugin from at jquery ajax call , all working fine can update the entry with the db class

```
$updateQuery = ee()->db->
            update('exp_channel_data',
                array(
                    'field_id_85' => "tester"
                ),
                array(
                    'field_id_73' => $user['userdata'][0]['field_id_73']
                )
        );
```

But I would like to trigger postmaster (entry updated)

```
$this->EE->api_channel_entries->save_entry($data, (int)$user['userdata'][0]['channel_id'], (int)$user['userdata'][0]['entry_id']);
```

Like descibed in the post link above - but getting an error - do I need to login or is there another way to trigger a postmaster parcel ?

any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Aha found out I have to be loggedin : ( using start , end session )

```
$this->startTempSession();

ee()->load->library('api');
ee()->api->instantiate('channel_entries');
ee()->api->instantiate('channel_fields');

ee()->api_channel_fields->setup_entry_settings($channel_id, $edit_array);
$saveResult = ee()->api_channel_entries->save_entry($edit_array, $channel_id , $entry_id , FALSE);
```

ee()->session->destroy();

Start and session destroy :

```
public function startTempSession()
{
    $ee = ee();
    if (!class_exists('Channel_from_session')) {
        require_once PATH_MOD . 'channel/libraries/channel_form/Channel_form_session.php';
    }

    $tmpSession = $ee->session;
    $tmpSession->userdata['can_edit_other_entries'] = 'y';

    $ee->session = new Channel_form_session(array(
        'session_object'       => $tmpSession,
        'logged_out_member_id' => 1,
        'logged_out_group_id'  => 1
        ));
}
```

Please comment if there is a better way of doing this :  just got here through trial n error ...